# How to debug angular js in chrome easy tricks?

Tags: angularjs, debugging

Hi i am working with angula  every time i have debug the code it will go into library files when i click the breakpoint in custom angular function i need to navigate to the next service or route when i stepinto  the function it will take more time to go for next function or service . when i step out it will provide the output in screen.

Consider i have angular app module in the controller i have injecting service,provider ,and routing etc.
Logic should be in services and i need to navigate the service logic how can easily navigate and debug in angular.it will take more time to return back to the certain logic.

-

Comment: you can use the chrome extension for debugging angular showing dynamic state of the pages'scope

Answer (score 0):

console.log() forever =) 
Sometimes I use [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) plugin for dev tools in chrome. This can show you modules, scopes, dependencies and performance. Can try use this;)

Comment: if i am calling the nested service and process  complex logics in services or factory , in the application level  there are  so many services and controllers are there .. if i need to step into line by line for getting the process like vs debugging . batarang will bind the scope values  and dom elements . when i stepinto means it will take more time to return back from the library files using developer tools .. consider some one have devlop the rapid app in angular you need to know the lifecylce of the app  in quick manner ?.. how can i do this.

Comment: I always use console.log() =) sometime use standart breakpoint for devtools